# The text of an old application is being attached to my current applications

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have been applying to jobs using Stack Jobs. I went back to look at my previous applications today.  In addition to the text I typed for the job application, it had, below that, attached the text from a job I applied to *272 weeks* ago!

I don't know why it added that. It was very discouraging, as it looked very unprofessional to the company to which those applications were going.

I'd like someone from Stack Overflow to contact me so we can get this bug figured out.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this! We've looked into this and it appears inexplicable to us how that old cover letter ended up right below your new one. None of our code is doing that, and we're unable to reproduce the issue. Any chance you have some sort of browser plugin installed? Would you be able to click through to the apply screen of another job and double-check the cover letter you're about to submit? Feedback from any of the +1s welcome as well.

Comment: For those jobs I only pasted the top half. I found the "addition" when I went to look at the application later. I didn't even know where it came from...until I started looking through old StackOverflow job applications, so no chance it would have been in my copy/paste buffer.

Comment: Installed extensions:

Doin't F*** with paste,
goo.gl URL shortner,
Google docs offline,
google hangouts,
Honey (installed after applications, if I recall correctly),
HTTPS Everywhere,
Okta browser plugin,
RightToCopy,
Video Speed Controller,
Docs,
Google Play Music,
Sheets,
Slides

Comment: Thanks for this additional information! For a possible explanation of what might have happened, see answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've spent quite some time investigating this, since it obviously sounds concerning. We're unable to reproduce this on our end and we haven't gotten any reports from other users experiencing the same problem.

Here's what might have happened: on the "Apply to " screen...

[image]

... the cover letter field ("Introduce yourself") gets pre-populated with whatever you entered last time - even if it was years ago.

I suspect that when you pasted your new cover letter, it didn't replace the old one. Instead, the new cover letter was inserted above the old one, which due to the size of the input field was no longer visible.

Maybe due to some erratic browser behavior, the old cover letter wasn't properly displayed; or it was displayed but it appeared selected (highlighted) so that it would have appeared that pasting the new one would replace the old one. Hard to say.

We'll keep an eye on this and check if we're getting additional reports of this happening.

Comment: Thank you for your research on this! It does appear that might have been the case. I think my previous submission might even have had a few blank lines at the beginning (or maybe something glitched and added them somewhere along the way). That would certainly explain why I didn't see it when I pasted the new letter. Thanks!